# How to implement a custom color method into code

Tags: objective-c, uicolor, objective-c-category

I have created a class containing code for a "customColor" that I want to implement into my code so that I can just type `buttonOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor customColor]`.

In the .h file, I have

```
+ (UIColor*) customColor;
```

and in the .m file, I have

```
+ (UIColor*) customColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.643 green:0.643 blue:0.643 alpha:1];
}
```

but when I go to "ViewController.m" and type in

```
buttonOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor customColor]
```

I get an error saying

> No known class method for selector `customColor`

I have imported the .h file. Is there a step I have missed out?

Comment: Is your custom class a category on UIColor?

Comment: Show the import and the category interface.

Comment: That should work. Perhaps show your complete .h and .m file for the UIColor category, and also how you import the .h file in ViewController.m.

Comment: Have you included the .m file in the targets Compile Sources? You can do this by clicking the .m file, then going to the right hand area and making sure that the .m file has its target membership set on the target. Alternatively Select the project, go to the 'build phases' tab and make sure the .m file is in the Compile Sources list.

Comment: @JamesSnook: Failing to add the .m file to the target would cause a *runtime exception* "unrecognized selector sent to instance", but not the *compiler error* shown above.

Comment: If my answer helped, would you mind checking the arrow next to it so the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you're trying to create a category without correctly declaring to the compiler this is a category of `UIColor`.  Here is an example of how to create your category:

---

Create the new catagory file as a new file > `Cocoa Touch` > `Objective-C category`.

I named my example `UIColor+CustomColorCatagory`.

In `UIColor+CustomColorCatagory.h`, change it to:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (CustomColorCatagory)   //This line is one of the most important ones - it tells the complier your extending the normal set of methods on UIColor
+ (UIColor *)customColor;

@end
```

In `UIColor+CustomColorCatagory.m`, change it to:

```
#import "UIColor+CustomColorCatagory.h"

@implementation UIColor (CustomColorCatagory)
+ (UIColor *)customColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.643 green:0.643 blue:0.643 alpha:1];
}
@end
```

Then in the places you want to use this method, add `#import "UIColor+CustomColorCatagory.h"`
and simply: `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor customColor];`